# php regex for checking a string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I need a regular expression for checking a string, that it has more than 2 symbols length, first symbol should be Alphabetic, last symbol should be '_'.

And how can I uppercase only first symbol?
Thank you.

Comment: please please read the documentation.

Comment: I know common regex rules. But I cannot to unite theirs.

Comment: cweiske may have meant (not to put words is his/her mouth) that if one is going to be dealing with strings in PHP, one should become familiar with the PHP string functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To match

```
preg_match( "/^[a-z].+_$/i", $str );
```

To uppercase the first letter

```
ucfirst( $str );
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
/^[a-zA-Z].+_$/
```

Note:
instead of `.+` you could use `[some allowed chars]+`

Answer (score 2):

To match an input with at least 3 char with first being uppercase alphabet and last begin underscore use:

```
^[A-Z].+_$
```

To allow any alphabet in the beginning you can use:

```
^[A-Za-z].+_$
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also do it like this (might save further regular expression dithering down the line):

```
if ((strlen($str) < 3) || !ctype_alpha($str[0]) || (strrchr($str, '_') != '_')) {
    echo 'Invalid string';
} else {
    $str = ucfirst($str);
}
```